# zsh variable assignment within if

Tags: macos, variables, zsh, iterm

This is my first question here so ... i hope i do it right.

I'm trying to write a little zsh script - following example simplifies what I have:

```
function example {
    if [ $1 == "my_string" ]; then
        local my_variable=10
    fi
    echo $my_variable
}

// i want
$> example my_string
$> 10

// i get
$> example:1: = not found
```

I've been trying with and without local variables, i tried declare and with or without spaces aswell as googling for hours.

t.i.a.

EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION
I'm using Mac OSX Mavericks - iTerm2 and I installed oh-my-zsh - this script is written directly within my ~/.zshrc

Comment: It works fine to me in `bash 4.2.47`. Are you in `bash` or `sh`?

Comment: `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: Your code seems to work ok. What exactly are you doing ? Which files are involved, what do you type in your terminal. Also, verify which shell you are actually using.

Comment: Works fine with bash 4.2.8 (Ubuntu 11.04) and bash 3.1.17 (RHEL 5).

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION gives me no output ... If i just type bash i see that it is 3.2.

Comment: It is Mac OSX Mavericks using iTerm2 and oh-my-zsh which shouldn't have a negative effect, right?

Comment: @adorak If you're using zsh, you surely arn't using bash - they're quite different. Please edit your question and tags so it becomes clear that this is about zsh and not bash.

Comment: What is `example:1:`?

Comment: @chepner I guess the OP is just typing `example:1:` in the console, same as `example my_string`.

Comment: Yes, but if that's true, it's no wonder he's getting a (presumed) "command not found" error.

Comment: @chepner yes, absolutely, `example:1:` is not defined so it is obviously not found.

Comment: @chepner `example:1:` is the output when running `example 10` with `zsh`. It is not the command. Admittedly the chosen representation used by the OP is not very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In zsh, when the `equals` option is set, typing `=program` will expand to the path to that program. Here, zsh is interpreting `==` as "path to the `=` program" and, not finding it, printing an error. You can either quote it or use `[[ ... ]]` instead.

Comment: adding the additional brackets solved all problems resulting in my function working just as expected. thank you

Comment: +1 Nice catch; I'm so used to seeing `==` as an operator with `[` that I never would have parsed that as `=` + something, as `zsh` does while parsing the arguments to `[`.

Comment: This behavior is confusing. When Zsh is parsing the command, `==` and `"my_string"` should have been in two tokens. For example, `echo =bash` prints the path to Bash, while `echo = bash` doesn’t. Why would it be different in the `[`? Both `echo` and `[` are Bash/Zsh built-in.

Comment: @FranklinYu I think you misunderstand. `==` and `"my_string"` are, correctly, being treated as two separate tokens. It's not failing to find the path to `my_string`, it's failing to find the path to `=`. Compare `echo = bash` with `echo == bash`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
example() {
    local my_variable
    [[ "$1" == "my_string" ]] && my_variable=10
    echo "$my_variable"
}
```

This is modern `bash` and works in `zsh` too. A couple of points:

1. the local declaration should be at the top or else you risk your echo's accessing "$my_variable" from the global scope if the condition isn't satisfied
2. `[` should be syntax sugar for `test` (an external program) whereas `[[` should be a builtin; prefer builtins (faster + smarter)
3. Always quote your variables unless you really know what you're doing (if you don't quote "$1", you'll get a syntax error inside `[[` if `$1` is empty.)
4. You can use `&&` or `||` for control flow if your `if` only has one branch (shorter).

Comment: thank you too for helping me out ... since I'm new to stackoverflow I don't know what is the usual way in marking the right answer, if there are multiple ... I'd like to give credit to everybody

Comment: Thanks for appreciating my answer. :) You can upvote all the answers that you have found to be helpful. People get points if their answers get upvoted. One answer you can also mark as your accepted answer (with the green checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
function example {
    if [ $1 == "my_string" ]; then
        local my_variable=10
    fi
    echo $my_variable
}
example my_string
```

This prints 10 for me (note: local: can only be used in a function, this is fine here, the call to the function must be done within the shell script itself, as shown above)

Comment: same result - since I'm not sure how to run it from an external file I also tried it my ~/.zshrc

Comment: @adorak, the example given is bash, for your mac, did you add #!/bin/bash in the beginning and make sure you are using bash

Comment: yes ... only difference is that the error is in line 2